# How do I update an element in a this vector?

Tags: ada

I am trying to update an element in a vector. I have quite a few issues that I don't know how to solve. When I use Replace_Element, everything works, but I want to use the proper procedure.

This is my code:

```
with Ada.Containers.Vectors;

procedure Test_Update is
    type Node is record
       Parent : Integer := -1;
       Size : Integer := -1;
    end record;

    function TestUpdate(n : Node; val : Integer) return Node is
    begin
        n.Size := n.Size + val;
        return n;
    end TestUpdate;

    package NodeVector is new
        Ada.Containers.Vectors
        (
            Index_Type   => Natural,
            Element_Type => Node
        );

    Nodes : NodeVector.vector;
    Current_Node : Node;

begin
    Current_Node.Size := 10;
    Nodes.Append(Current_Node);
    NodeVector.Update_Element(Nodes, 0, TestUpdate'Access(5));
    --NodeVector.Update_Element(Nodes, 0, TestUpdate'Access);
end Test_Update;
```

These are the errors that I am getting, and I know what is causing them, but no idea how to fix them:

```
test_update.adb:11:09: error: assignment to "in" mode parameter not allowed
test_update.adb:28:59: error: unexpected argument for "Access" attribute
```

When I use the code in the comments, and remove the second parameter for the function, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a lot of things mixed up here.  First if you look at Zerte's answer more carefully than before, you'll notice that your TestUpdate operation doesn't match that Process argument at all.  It expects a procedure (you have a function) and the procedure's parameter is "in out" while you are using "in" and you have an additional parameter.  You need to fix this first

If you want to use Update_Element (I don't recommend it for your specific case) then you need to look into "[Nested Subprograms](https://learn.adacore.com/courses/intro-to-ada/chapters/subprograms.html#nested-subprograms)".  Here is an example of how to change your TestUpdate operation to work with Update_Element:

```ada
procedure TestUpdate(V : in out NodeVector.Vector; val : Integer) is
    procedure Actual_Update(N : in out Node) is
    begin
        n.Size := n.Size + val;
    end Actual_Update;
begin
    V.Update_Element(V.Last,Actual_Update'Access);
end TestUpdate;
```

Notice how the Actual_Update procedure actually matches the process argument of the Update_Element operation contract.  Additionally, since Actual_Update is nested, it has access to the Val argument from TestUpdate.

Full example:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Containers.Vectors;

procedure Test_Update is
    type Node is record
       Parent : Integer := -1;
       Size : Integer := -1;
    end record;

    package NodeVector is new
        Ada.Containers.Vectors
        (
            Index_Type   => Natural,
            Element_Type => Node
        );

    Nodes : NodeVector.vector;
    Current_Node : Node;
    
    procedure TestUpdate(V : in out NodeVector.Vector; val : Integer) is
        procedure Actual_Update(N : in out Node) is
        begin
            n.Size := n.Size + val;
        end Actual_Update;
    begin
        V.Update_Element(V.Last,Actual_Update'Access);
    end TestUpdate;
    
begin
    Current_Node.Size := 10;
    Nodes.Append(Current_Node);
    TestUpdate(Nodes, 5);
end Test_Update;
```

With Vectors, you can also just index things directly.  After you append an item, you can use <vector_name>.Last to get the cursor (index) for the last element...the one you just added.  Example:

```ada
with Ada.Text_IO; use Ada.Text_IO;
with Ada.Containers.Vectors;

procedure Test_Update is
    type Node is record
       Parent : Integer := -1;
       Size : Integer := -1;
    end record;

    package NodeVector is new
        Ada.Containers.Vectors
        (
            Index_Type   => Natural,
            Element_Type => Node
        );

    Nodes : NodeVector.vector;
    Current_Node : Node;
    
    procedure Using_Cursors
        (V : in out NodeVector.Vector;
         N : Node;
         Value : Integer)
    is begin
        Nodes.Append(N);
        Nodes(Nodes.Last).Size := Nodes(Nodes.Last).Size + Value;
    end Using_Cursors;
    
begin
    Current_Node.Size := 10;
    Using_Cursors(Nodes,Current_Node,5);
end Test_Update;
```

Comment: Thank you for such a complete answer. I thought that a function was a type of procedure, and I gerenally had no idea how to do something like this. I do want to add that when I tried to access the element directly, using similar code to the last example, it said "left hand side of assignment must be a variable." Also, you said that you don't recommend using Update_Element; do you recommend using Replace_Element instead?

Comment: @Josh That error about the variable is because you were using the "in" mode parameter instead of "in out".  Parameters that are "in" mode only are essentially constant and "non-variable".  Parameters that are "in out" can be changed are considered "variable".  It was complaining because you were trying to change a constant parameter.

Comment: I recommend just using the indexing operations (like at the bottom of my answer) unless you need to use the Update_Element.  The Update_Element part calls can be kinda clunky to both use correctly and to read.  Replace_Element is fine as well as long as that does what you want.  You can also access them via NodeVector.Element function calls.  You can also do a "for of" loop if the elements are already in the vector before you need to update them.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Web search will lead you to...
[A.18.2 The Package Containers.Vectors](https://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rm/html/RM-A-18-2.html)
(or, if you use GNAT Studio: right-click on "Vectors" in "Ada.Containers.Vectors", then choose Go To Declaration).
Then you will find this:

```
procedure Update_Element
     (Container : in out Vector;
      Index     : in     Index_Type;
      Process   : not null access procedure
                      (Element : in out Element_Type));
```

Comment: Yes I found that, but I am very new and I have no idea how to use that information. That's how I found the procedure in the first place, but I don't know how the Process parameter works.